# Javascript undefined but formula is present

Tags: javascript

I'm really scratching my head at this one. I'm getting an error that calculateHelper is undefined... but.... isn't it right in the function?? I first thought it was an order thing, so I've even moved the entire `var calculateHelper` to above the `if(valuesArr)` statement, or moved it outside the `buy_vs_rent` event handler, none of that helped.

```
$('#buy_vs_rent_calculate').on('click', function(){

  if(valuesArr.length === 1){
    setTimeout("calculateHelper(valuesArr[0])",100);
  } else {
    alert("Please set three of the four values using the sliders; leave only one field blank to be calculated")
  }

  var calculateHelper = function(valueToCalc){
    ... 
  };
});
```

Comment: Why do you have calculateHelper method in quotes?

Comment: @MaxZoom You can use quotes in `setTimeout` and it will work, it's just not recommened.

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should. It's basically doing an eval.

Comment: Once my boss forced me to use Nr 1 internet company undocumented weather service. It was working over one year and then one day it stopped. Since then I try to avoid undocumented features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `calculateHelper` is defined locally and calling a function (`calculateHelper(valuesArr[0])`) doesn't make it a function (as said by @[Spencer Wieczorek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3149020/spencer-wieczorek)) --> `setTimeout` first parameter must be a function reference, change it into something like this:

```
$('#buy_vs_rent_calculate').on('click', function(){
  var calculateHelper = function(valueToCalc){
    ... 
  }; // move up
  if(valuesArr.length === 1){
    setTimeout(function(){
      calculateHelper(valuesArr[0]); // don't use string for local function
    },100);
  } else {
    alert("Please set three of the four values using the sliders; leave only one field blank to be calculated")
  }
});
```

Comment: *"I first thought it was an order thing, so I've even moved the entire `var calculateHelper` to above the `if(valuesArr)` statement"*.

Comment: oh... ok I feel silly asking, are local functions called differently? I'm not fully understanding why I need the `function () { calculateHelper ] )` as opposed to just `calculateHelper`

Comment: @Kokizzu It's because the anonymous wrapper `function(){...}`prevents the function from self executing right away. It can have parameters. There is a difference between an item that is a *function* vs a *function call*. `setTimeout` takes a function as the first parameters, simply calling a function does not make it a `function` itself.

Comment: you can pass the function name, but without parameters : setTimeout(calculateHelper,100); and then access global valuesArr[0] in the  calculateHelper method

Comment: Thanks everyone! Learned so much from this post

Answer (score 5):

When you pass a string to `setTimeout` it is resolved to code in the global context. However your `calculateHelper` is defined as a local variable.

```
$('#buy_vs_rent_calculate').on('click', function(){

  if(valuesArr.length === 1){
    setTimeout(function () { calculateHelper(valuesArr[0]); },100);
  } else {
    alert("Please set three of the four values using the sliders; leave only one field blank to be calculated")
  }

  var calculateHelper = function(valueToCalc){
    ... 
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call setTimeout as

```
setTimeout(function() { calculateHelper(valuesArr[0]); } ,100);
```

See this function [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) for more info.

Comment: This form is preferable when you want to pass parameters to the function, as it works in all browsers including IE ! ;)